# Email - Como inciar en cuenta corporativa outlook y enviar un correo a otras cuentas?

Tags: php, html, phpmailer, outlook

Tengo un tema que es enviar un correo usando outlook, al correo que quiero iniciar es uno corporativo que esta vinculado con microsoft exchange, el correo seria asi: miuser@dominio_empresa.co, ojo .CO

Yo use la libreria de phpmailer, pude iniciar en una cuenta de @gmail.com y @outlook.com y enviar un correo desde esas cuentas, pero cuando trato de poner como origen una cuenta corporativa ( @dominio_empresa.co ) pues me da error de autenticacion. Yo supongo que es por el host que esta mal.

Mas tarde use y modifique sendmail.exe, configure el php.ini y sendmail.ini, agregue los datos de host, puerto y correo con pass pero aun asi me da porblemas de autenticaion.

Tengo que resaltar que aqui tenemos nuestra red llamada BeOne, esa es la red corporativa, en esa red es donde tenemos las base de datos que usamos para las aplicaciones que tenemos aqui.

**Codigo de sendmail.ini:**

```
; configuration for fake sendmail

; if this file doesn't exist, sendmail.exe will look for the settings in
; the registry, under HKLM\Software\Sendmail

[sendmail]

; you must change mail.mydomain.com to your smtp server,
; or to IIS's "pickup" directory.  (generally C:\Inetpub\mailroot\Pickup)
; emails delivered via IIS's pickup directory cause sendmail to
; run quicker, but you won't get error messages back to the calling
; application.

smtp_server=smtp.office365.com

; smtp port (normally 25)

smtp_port=587

; SMTPS (SSL) support
;   auto = use SSL for port 465, otherwise try to use TLS
;   ssl  = alway use SSL
;   tls  = always use TLS
;   none = never try to use SSL

smtp_ssl=tls

; the default domain for this server will be read from the registry
; this will be appended to email addresses when one isn't provided
; if you want to override the value in the registry, uncomment and modify

default_domain=empresa.co

; log smtp errors to error.log (defaults to same directory as sendmail.exe)
; uncomment to enable logging

error_logfile=error.log

; create debug log as debug.log (defaults to same directory as sendmail.exe)
; uncomment to enable debugging

debug_logfile=debug.log

; if your smtp server requires authentication, modify the following two lines

auth_username=amperezp@empresa.co
auth_password=xxxxxxxxxx

; if your smtp server uses pop3 before smtp authentication, modify the 
; following three lines.  do not enable unless it is required.

pop3_server=
pop3_username=
pop3_password=

; force the sender to always be the following email address
; this will only affect the "MAIL FROM" command, it won't modify 
; the "From: " header of the message content

force_sender=amperezp@empresa.co

; force the sender to always be the following email address
; this will only affect the "RCTP TO" command, it won't modify 
; the "To: " header of the message content

force_recipient=

; sendmail will use your hostname and your default_domain in the ehlo/helo
; smtp greeting.  you can manually set the ehlo/helo name if required

hostname=localhost
```

**Codigo de php:**

```
$head = "MINE-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$head .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
if (mail('amperezp@empresa.co', 'Asunto', '<div>Body</div>', $head)){
    echo 'Mensaje enviado';
} else {
    echo 'No enviado';
}
```

Como yo podria iniciar en una cuenta corporativa exchange para que desde ahi envie un correo?

Comment: hay algunos ejemplos googleando un poco, no estoy seguro si esto te ayude https://gist.github.com/joseluisq/709543d65cbfc117168d760e5223f76a

Comment: En verdad no ayuda mucho que digamos, para alguien que no ha visto phpmailer si, pero en este caso no. Me gustaria saber hasta que dominio poner si mi cuenta de correo es corporativa